# Cómo seleccionar aleatoriamente más de dos valores en un array en JS

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en Javascript y queria saber como puedo obtener más de 2 valores que sean totalmente aleatorios de este array

```js
let frutas = ['manzana','banana','uva','sandía','melón']
```

Comment: No te voy a dar una respuesta directamente porque dices ser nuevo... Entonces eso sería obstruir el proceso de aprendizaje. Pero te sugiero que generes dos números randoms que vayan del rango de 0 al largo del array-1 y luego utilices estos dos números para acceder  a dos elementos del array... Dos elementos random.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo ir al [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla!, ya que para ayudarte, necesitamos saber lo que [intentastes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener 2 o más elementos distintos del array, recomiendo mejor es desordenar el array, y luego coger la cantidad de elementos que necesites:

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
}

function randomElements(array, quantity) {
  return shuffleArray([...array]).slice(0, quantity);
}
let frutas = ['manzana','banana','uva','sandía','melón', 'pera', 'naranja', 'piña'];

console.log(randomElements(frutas,2));
console.log(randomElements(frutas,4));
console.log(randomElements(frutas,6));
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarme qué es lo que hacen exactamente las funciones **shuffleArray** y **randomElement**?

Comment: Claro... `shuffleArray` lo que hace es ordenar de manera aleatoria el array (O sea desordenarlo), usando el algogoritmo Fisher-Yates (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates). `randomElements` lo que hace es desordenar el array y tomar la cantidad de elementos especificados por `quantity` del array desordenado.

Comment: @Pipe Si bien lo que pusistes respondio a la pregunta, ten encuenta que simplemente le resolvistes y ya sin que el OP pusiera lo que intento y esto es lo que tratamos de evitar en el sitio, preguntas mal formuladas con respuestas. Se debe seguir un lineamiento como dice el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) "*Cosas que no hayas buscado una solución (muestra tu trabajo!)*"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la Función `Math.random()` que te devolverá un número aleatorio entre 0 y 1, haciendo uso de esta función, puedes multiplicarlo por el máximo número aleatorio que quieres tener y redondearlo con la ayuda de `Math.floor()`, el código se vería de la siguiente manera:

`Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));` // arroja un número random

Ahora, si lo que quieres es 2 números random de tu array, solo deber generar dos números random y usarlos como índice de tu array. De la siguiente manera:

```js
let frutas = ['manzana','banana','uva','sandía','melón'];
let random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) );
let random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) );

console.log(frutas[random1]);
console.log(frutas[random2]);
```

Comment: Advertencia: Esto podría generar 2 veces el mismo elemento

Comment: Pues sí, pero solo se pedían que los número sean aleatorios, no pidieron que no se repitieran esos números.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo indagar el metodo Math.random(), este mismo genera un valor aleatorio, el cual si lo combinas con el metodo Math.floor() o Math.ceil() vas a poder redondearlo hacia arriba o abajo, dependiendo de lo que quieras. Luego podes multiplicar ese valor para que el numero este dentro del largo de los elemtos del Array.
Dominando eso el paso siguiente es que generes ese numero aleatorio entre 0 y el total de elementos.
Te dejo esto como ejemplo para que puedas darte una idea y no sea tan abstracto.

```js
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
    //Math.ceil()redondea el numero que generas con Math.random(), y lo colocas dentro de los parentesis ()
    let numeroAleatorio= Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)
    //Lo multiplicas por el numero hasta el cual queres llegar, en este ej, puse 5
    console.log(numeroAleatorio);
}
```